# ontouchstart acting weird on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, phaser-framework, ontouchstart

I am working on a game and i am using ontouchstart as a way to handle au ser tapping on the screen. but when i click on the screen it does not register the first time, it makes me click it  twice for it to register even one click. I have no idea what to do. does anyone know a fix?

I decided to update my code with a more simplified version of it. this is not working either. on an IOS device at least, no matter what browser i use, i have to tap twice for it to register once.

```
<html>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <body>
        <h1 class="center-align" id="cn">click me</h1>
        <h2 id="cl">clicked:</h2>
    </body>
    <script>
        let click = 1;

        document.getElementById("cn").ontouchstart = () => {
            click++;
            document.getElementById("cl").innerHTML = "clicked: " + click;
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you try removing the `touch-action` from the styles? Manipulating touch action ends up affecting touch event listeners

EDIT

Can you try this instead?

```
object.addEventListener("touchstart", myScript);
```

Comment: thank you, just tried it but it is still not working.

Comment: That looked like the solution tbh, but i tried it and still no. :(

Comment: I went ahead and updated my question though, i tried it with some simple code and it is doing the same thing on my phone. i need to click twice for it to register. so weird..

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEO03GCJ605R can you try this on your mobile phone please?

Comment: thank you, it didn't solve the issue but i realized what was wrong with it. apparently mobile browsers have a 300ms delay, so if you press before that time iit wont register.